# How to skip corrupted messages in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

How to skip corrupted Messages in Flink

I have DAG: KafkaSrcConsumer > FlatMap > Window > SinkFunction

Now if I get corruptedMessage from Kafka in operator "KafkaSrcConsumer", I want to throw/skip that message and I don't want to forward that corrupted message to next operator "FlatMap"

How can we achieve this in Apache Flink ?

(Note: throwing exception from KafkaSrcConsumer will restart flink job and I want to avoid that as I just want to skip message and move to next message)

Comment: Did you consider using a Filter operation after KafkaSrcConsumer and before FlatMap to check the messages and skip corrupted messages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `deserialize(...)` method returns null, the Flink Kafka consumer will silently skip the corrupted message. This is described [in the documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/dev/connectors/kafka.html#the-deserializationschema).

Comment: On a related note, the sink counterpart was finally addressed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29480.